# Getting an INVALID_REQUEST Uber API

Tags: uber-api

In this call to Uber API:

```
curl -F 'client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>' \
   -F 'client_id=<CLIENT_ID>' \
   -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
   -F 'redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>' \
   -F 'scope=profile' \
   -F 'code=<AUTHORIZATION_CODE>' \
   https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token
```

<sub>from: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v2/token-post</sub>

It was working before, but now I am getting this error:

```
{
   "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

Where can I find more details about it? 
At least know which of the parameters is wrong or invalid?

Comment: Hello-- I know the team that works on identity at Uber just rolled back some changes. Can you try the same thing you are currently doing now and reply on if it works or you are still having trouble?

Comment: Now it's working.